# Laurent series for f(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find Laurent series for $f(z)$ at $z=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ where

$$
f(z)=\frac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1+\sin z}
$$

I defined $z=-\frac{\pi}{2}+t$ and did the expansion of the denominator around $t=0$. I am kind of stuck what to do for the numerator. Any hints?

Comment: $$\sqrt{-\frac{\pi}{2} + t} = \sqrt{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \left( 1 - \frac{2t}{\pi}\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: $z^{1/2}=i(\frac{\pi}{2})^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}$, where $x=\frac{2t}{\pi}$